# What is the difference between inserting an option and without in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Can anyone help me with implementing jQuery UI? I am slightly confused whenever I want to customize certain jQuery UI and that requires the usage of options. I noticed from the documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) that sometimes you add in additional parameters like :

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

whereas sometimes you don't need :

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 });
```

Both will come up with the same result. Are there any differences between the two?

Comment: The first one changes an option on an already instantiated widget, the second instantiates a widget and provides the initial option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 })` - used to set option on init

`$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 )` - used to set option after init.

From the link you provided:

> Initialize the accordion with the active option specified:
>   ...
>
> Get or set the active option, after initialization:

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6q4sv6ov/). There are two accortion. First initialized without parameters, and button trigger activating of third item.  Second initialized with already activated third item. This is a difference.